# SQLiteDatabase.OpenDatabase is NullPointerException in Fragment

Tags: android, database, android-fragments

This works outside of fragment `onCreateView` but not in that static method.

```
SQLiteDatabase checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path_to + DATABASE_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

I have a `DataBaseHelper` which is initialized outside the static method as

```
FeedReaderHelper mHelper = new FeedReaderHelper(this);
```

whereas for fragment, I use

```
if (getActivity() != null)
    FeedReaderHelper xHelper = new FeedReaderHelper(getActivity());
else
    Log.d(TAG, "Null");
```

I know that `getActivity` is not null and the error persists even if I only try to open and close the database. My logcat goes like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

I don't get what `Resources` means here and how to avoid the error altogether.

Also, I've tried opening the database before `onContentView` is called; it still resolves to NullPointer upon `checkDB.close`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `FeedReederHelper` only to call `db.exec()` statements whereupon the same Helper should have been used to open database without the hard-coded path in `checkDB` call.
`mHelper.getWriteableDatabase();` solved the issue.